# System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, object, serialization, windows-phone-8

I am trying to save an object into isolated storage but received `A first chance exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll`

My object class

```
[DataContract]
public class NoteContent : IEnumerable
{
    [DataMember] 
    public Microsoft.Phone.Controls.SupportedPageOrientation SupportedOrientation{ get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public List<Character> NoteCharacterList { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public string NoteFileName { get; set; }

    private List<Character> notecontent = new List<Character>();

    public void Add(Character charObj)
    {
        notecontent.Add(charObj);
        NoteCharacterList = notecontent;
    }

    public void Clear()
    {
        notecontent.Clear();
    }

    public Character this[int id]
    {
        get { return notecontent[id]; }
    }

    public IEnumerator<Character> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return notecontent.GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

The code I am using to serialize and save the object. The error was raised at this line `_mySerializer.WriteObject(targetFile, sourceData);`

```
    public void SaveMyData(NoteContent sourceData, String targetFileName)
    {
        string TargetFileName = String.Format("{0}/{1}.dat", TargetFolderName, targetFileName);

        using (IsolatedStorageFile store = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
        {

            if (!store.DirectoryExists(TargetFolderName))
                store.CreateDirectory(TargetFolderName);
            try
            {
                using (var targetFile = store.CreateFile(TargetFileName))
                {
                    _mySerializer.WriteObject(targetFile, sourceData);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                store.DeleteFile(TargetFileName);
            }
        }

    }
```

The object contains a list of objects and controls.

[image]

The list of objects inside the main object to be saved
[image]

Is it because I cannot serialize objects like image control and canvas controls? What is the best approach to save such object into isolated storage?

**UPDATE 1**

I've simplified my object to only include the following properties but am still getting the same error. Are Points and Char serializable?

```
    public Point ImagePosition { get; set; }
    public Char CharText { get; set; }
    public double ImageDegree { get; set; }
    public double ImageScale { get; set; }
    public int ImageZOrder { get; set; }
    public bool IsResizeCancel { get; set; }
    public double MaxSliderValue { get; set; }
    public double CurrentWidth { get; set; }
    public double CurrentHeight { get; set; }
```

Comment: Why can't you do this? Because you're meant to serialize the data, not the entire UI tree.

Comment: So if I remove the Canvas and Image controls and composite transform object, it should be ok?

Comment: Maybe - it depends if all the objects you're trying to save are Serializable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solved it. I simplified my object by removing properties that may not serialized using [Copying object to another object but remove certain properties Windows Phone 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681809/copying-object-to-another-object-but-remove-certain-properties-windows-phone-8/15681831#15681831)

The simplified class

```
[DataContract]
public class CharacterClone
{
    [DataMember] 
    public Point ImagePosition { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public Char CharText { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public double ImageDegree { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public double ImageScale { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public int ImageZOrder { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public bool IsResizeCancel { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public double MaxSliderValue { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public double CurrentWidth { get; set; }
    [DataMember] 
    public double CurrentHeight { get; set; }

    public CharacterClone(Character original)
    { 
        ImagePosition = original.ImagePosition;
        CharText = original.CharText;
        ImageDegree = original.ImageDegree;
        ImageScale = original.ImageScale;
        ImageZOrder = original.ImageZOrder;
        IsResizeCancel = original.IsResizeCancel;
        MaxSliderValue = original.MaxSliderValue;
        CurrentWidth = original.CurrentWidth;
        CurrentHeight = original.CurrentHeight;
    }
}
```

And another important thing to note is the file path. In WP8 the separator should be `\\` instead of `/` such as

```
string TargetFileName = String.Format("{0}\\{1}.dat", TargetFolderName, targetFileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this class and on save it throw the same exception

An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException' occurred in System.Runtime.Serialization.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

```
    [DataContract]
class UserInfo :SerializationException
{
    //  Constructors: 
    public UserInfo() { }
    public UserInfo(String username,String password) {
        Username = username;
        Password = password;
    }
   [DataMember] 
    public String Username
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
   [DataMember] 
    public String Password
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```