# Copying object to another object but remove certain properties Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, object, copy, windows-phone-8, clone

I want to copy an object to another but remove certain properties. Eg

```
public  class A
{
    public bool IsResizeCancel { get; set; }
    public double MaxSliderValue { get; set; }
    public double CurrentWidth { get; private set; }
    public double CurrentHeight { get; private set; }
}
```

Copy object A to object B but remove the CurrentWidth and CurrentHeight properties

```
public class B
{
    public bool IsResizeCancel { get; set; }
    public double MaxSliderValue { get; set; }
}
```

How to do this efficiently with the least amount of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
public class B
{
    public B(A a)
    {
        IsResizeCancel = a.IsResizeCancel;
        MaxSliderValue = a.MaxSliderValue;
    }
    public bool IsResizeCancel { get; set; }
    public double MaxSliderValue { get; set; }
}
```